# How can be sure that I've found all possible solutions to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that in order to solve $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix we just form $[A\vert b]$, row reduce to $\mathrm{rref}[A\vert b]$, if this has a row of $0$'s with a $1$ at the end then we are done and say there are no solutions, if not 'we set parameters to all variables corresponding to non-pivot columns and write the rest of the variables in term of this parameters using the correspondence between the matrix and the represented equations'. My question is how do we know that the process described between the quotes will yield *all* solutions to the system.

Comment: By seeing elementary row operations as playing with the given equations, each step is an if and only if. Therefore, the final result will yield all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reason with the statement is to look at an example. Let's say you have the following system of equations:
$$\begin{align}2x+3y &=1 \\x+y+z&=0 \end{align}.$$

Since we have two equations, we can solve for two variables *in terms* of a third. Let's choose $y$ and $z$:
$$
\begin{align}
y&=\frac{1-2x}{3}\\
z&=\frac{-x-1}{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since we don't know what $x$ is, we set it as a *parameter* so that it can take any value in the field of interest. In the case of the reals, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This makes sense because we don't have enough information to restrict $x$ to be any explicit value. By letting $x$ take on ANY value, we can successfully represent ALL solutions to the system.